# PHP + Nginx + X-Accel-Redirect Caching issue

Tags: php, caching, nginx

I am using nginx 1.0.12 and have a setup like this:

```
        location /protected/ {
            expires 30d;
            log_not_found off;
            internal;
            alias /var/www/files/uploads/;
    }
```

and am requesting user files like this:

```
header('X-Accel-Redirect: http://example.com/adetwiler/files/example.png');
header('Content-type: image/png');
```

Everything works great up until the point where the user can rotate their image. Once they rotate their image, I can't figure out how to get the "new" version of the file, it's still showing the older version of the image, unless "refresh" is clicked on the browser.

I have tried to set Cache-control: no-cache, Expires: Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT, no luck with those.

I tried adding the modified date like so:

```
header('X-Accel-Redirect: http://example.com/adetwiler/files/example.png?123456789');
```

That caused the image to load everytime when I tried that.

I tried adding this to the nginx config:

```
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate";
```

At this point I am at a loss, I have tried everything that I could think of.

So my question is, is there a way with my current setup or something similar to my setup to use the newer version of the image once the image is updated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like setting `X-Accel-Buffering: no` as a header tells nginx not to cache the response at all.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/